# How to setting context root in web.xml in servlet ??

Tags: java, xml, jsp, tomcat, servlets

setting context root path in **web.xml** in servlet, How i can achieve
it dynamically adding context root
For Instance : My project name is MyTestApp and I want to set
context root as **/myapp**  and hit on browser as **localhost:8080/myapp**

Comment: If you use Netbeans :

**Properties > Run > Context Path**

Comment: In Eclipse also we have facility :**  Project > Properties > Web Project Settings > [ Name of context root ] ** but i have to achieve it using web.xml @YoucefLaidani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delete `ROOT` webapp from Tomcat.

From Tomcat documentation : http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_override_the_default_home_page_loaded_by_Tomcat.3F

> The pages and code of your "mywebapp" application currently reside in
>   (CATALINA_BASE)/webapps/mywebapp/. In a standard Tomcat installation,
>   you will notice that under the same directory
>   (CATALINA_BASE)/webapps/, there is a directory called ROOT (the
>   capitals are important, even under Windows). That is the residence of
>   the current Tomcat default application, the one that is called right
>   now when a user calls up "http://myhost.company.com[:port]". The trick
>   is to put your application in its place.
>
> First stop Tomcat. Then before you replace the current default
>   application, it may be a good idea to make a copy of it somewhere
>   else. Then delete everything under the ROOT directory, and move
>   everything that was previously under the
>   (CATALINA_BASE)/webapps/mywebapp/ directory, toward this
>   (CATALINA_BASE)/webapps/ROOT directory. In other words, what was
>   previously .../mywebapp/WEB-INF should now be .../ROOT/WEB-INF (and
>   not .../ROOT/mywebapp/WEB-INF).
>
> Just by doing this, you have already made you webapp into the Tomcat
>   default webapp.
>
> Restart Tomcat and you're done. Call up "http://myhost.company.com/"
>   and enjoy.

Comment: Well, this is not actually setting the context root path for your project. This is just replacing ROOT application with yours. What if we want specifically to set the root path of our app?

Comment: If you're using Tomcat, this is how you have to do it. This is not a trick or a workaroung that I created to do it. This is the official documentation. If you have another solution, I'd be glad to ear it.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mickael. Could you please provide the official docs where Apache states that?
Also, what IntelliJ does then, when you provide in the configuration context path / ? does it delete ROOT?